# Extending a scala class with less ceremony

Tags: scala

I am probably doing something wrong.
When I extend a class, I specify the mapping between the extendee's constructor and the extended class constructor:

```
class Base(one: String, two: String)
case class Extended(one: String, two: String, three: String) extends Base(one, two)
```

How can I instead suffice with something like any of the following, thus implying a "default" mapping?

```
class Base(one: String, two: String) 
case class Extended(one: String, two: String, three: String) extends Base

class Base(one: String, two: String) 
case class Extended(three: String) extends Base
```

I am probably missing the cleaner way of just adding a parameter without all that ceremony.
Or should I be using a trait rather than subclassing, for such simple thing....

Comment: There are reasons besides convenience for simpler syntax of "pass-thru" class params: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4762

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All the parameters of a `case` class generated `apply` method have to be specified in the `case` class declaration, so your second proposal cannot work. The first one can be accomplished if `Base` is abstract, using abstract `val`s:

```
abstract class Base {
  // no initializers!
  val one : String
  val two : String

  def print { println("Base(%s, %s)" format (one, two)) }
}
// Note: constructor arguments of case classes are vals!
case class Extended(one: String, two: String, three: String) extends Base
...
Extended("foo", "bar", "baz").print // prints 'Base(foo, bar)'
```

However, the names need to match exactly.